# Ajax update in a Sharepoint 2010 Webpart

Tags: ajax, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

Is there any easy way to make a Ajax call in a Webpart?

I have a Webpart with a button, and I want that when the user pushes the button, it executes a server function without reloading the page. And then, if all is ok, execute a callback function. I thought that the best way is with a AJAX call.

But when I've looked for how to do it I only get some complicated tutorials that I don't really understand (and most are from old versions of Sharepoint). Any help? What is the best way to start? Thanks

Comment: it depends of what you want to do. The Javascript Client Object Model is a good place to start, or even jQuery. Please describe the kind of process you want to do on the callback.

Comment: Well, the callback function only have to close a popup. And if something wrong happens, then show an alert("ERROR")

Comment: Are you still experiencing any issues?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using jQuery with a content editor web part? I've done this before and it's rather easy. Here is a step by step for how I do it.

1. Download [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery).
2. Upload jQuery to SiteAssets in Sharepoint.
3. Upload coded file (see below) with AJAX calls.
4. Point to coded file via Content Editor Web Part.
5. It should work!

Here is a default way something should work.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="<point to jquery file>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#main').load('<RELATIVE URL TO SERVER PAGE>');
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't think that we have a "'<RELATIVE URL TO SERVER PAGE>'". We only have a mainClass.cs with a C# method saveContent(). Is it possible call this method saveContent() from the javascript call?

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you want, it's hard to answer your question, but I'll give it a shot! Try putting your C# on an ASPX code behind page. What exactly does your save content function do?

Answer (score 0):

If possible I would go for a Visual Web Part in Visual Studio. You basically create a .NET user control. It saves you a lot of manual control definitions etc.

If in SharePoint2007 you might want to take a look at the "Smartpart". It has ajax support and some great tutorials on how to use it.